# ASCII character not being recognized in if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

I am trying to get a string from a html page with jquery and this is what I have.

```
var text = $(this).text();

var key = text.substring(0,1);
if(key == ' ' || key == '&#160;')
    key = text.substring(1,2);


text is this &#160;Home
```

And I want to skip the space and or the keycode above It appears this code does not work either. It only gets the text.substring(0,1); instead of text.substring(1,2); because the if statement is not catching.= and I am not sure why. Any help would be super awesome! Thanks!

Comment: `key` is a single character and `&#160;` is six characters, so they'll never match. The HTML entities are not converted in JS code. You need to compare to the actual unicode character or an appropriate JavaScript escape sequence.

Comment: But I do not understand how I could do this. I tried changing the code to the escape sequence in JS so I changed the key == '&#160' to key == '\u0020' but still does not work. If this is what you meant.

Comment: Use this: `key == "\u00A0"`

Comment: Use `===` it type matches. `==` can lead to hidden issues with primitives.

Comment: @Sukima: If the type matches, there's no difference between `==` and `===`.

Comment: @cookiemonster except that if you make using `==` a habit then you will find trouble down the road. Hence why experienced programmers will tell you to use `===` instead.

Comment: @Sukima: Experienced programmers will know when it makes a difference and when it doesn't, and will decide accordingly. I was just responding to your comment where you said to use `===` if the type matches, which doesn't make sense. If the type matches, then there's no difference between the two. The `==` only gets hairy when the types *don't* match, because that's when the type coercive algorithm takes over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want remove spaces at the beginning (and end) of a string, you can use the trim function

```
var myvar = " home"
myVar.trim() // --> "home"
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Comment: I tried that before and it doesnt remove it for some reason.
EDIT--------------------------------------------------------
Omg I feel stupid now. I was putting the trim in the wrong spot the whole time. I tried this before but put it after the first one (dont ask why theres more to this function) But it def works lol... SOrry guys. But thanks the help!

Comment: Yeah but I did myVar = myVar.trim(); But I feel stupid. I edited my last post :P. You guys are awesome! Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not a fan of w3schools, but this downvoting merely for linking to it has got to stop. It's utterly stupid behavior.

Comment: For completeness: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim (PS: I did not downvote)

Comment: In addition to citing a horrendously unreliable site, this answer uses `trim` for a simple operation that can be performed in a simple cross-browser manner (`trim` is not supported by old versions of IE) *and* it removes all whitespace at the start and at the end. The question asks for code that removes one space or one no-break space at the start.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: This answer read into what the OP was ultimately wanting to do, and gave an appropriate solution. It's not likely that the OP would want to prevent a single space, but would be satisfied with two or more. The docs cited are sufficient for the answer he gave, and provide the browser support information if needed.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with the code in the question. First, `&#160;` has no special meaning in JavaScript: it is a string literal with six characters. Second, `text.substring(1,2)` returns simply the second character of `text`, not all characters from the second one onwards.

Assuming that you wish to remove one leading SPACE or NO-BREAK SPACE (which is what `&#160;` means in HTML; it is not an Ascii character, by the way), then the following code would work:

```
var first = text.substring(0, 1);
if(first === ' ' || first === '\u00A0') {
   text = text.substring(1, text.length);
}
```

The notation `\u00A0` is a JavaScript escape notation for NO-BREAK SPACE U+00A0.

Should you wish to remove multiple spaces at the start, and perhaps at the end too, some modifications are needed. In that case, using a replace operation with regular expression is probably best.